# Why do I get Uncaught TypeError while I've defined it?

Tags: javascript, html, undefined, typeerror

I'm trying to make a quiz, here is the html :

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>English Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="testCss.css">
</head>

<body>
    <br>
    <div style="font-size:20px">
    <p>Please choose the correct answer and at the end tap the score button. </p>

<br>
<div>
    2. I
    <select id="question2">
        <option value="_">_</option>
        <option value="Am">am</option>
        <option value="Is">is</option>
        <option value="Are">are</option>
    </select>
    22 years old.
    <span id="question2_answer"></span>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div>
    101. When can we meet again?
    <span id="question101_answer"></span>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="question101" > When are you free?<br>
        <input type="radio" name="question101" > It was two days ago. <br>
        <input type="radio" name="question101" > Can you help me?
    </div>
</div>
<br> 
<br>
<div>
    8. What is your father like?
    <span id="question8_answer"></span>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="question8" > He likes listenning to music.<br>
        <input type="radio" name="question8" > He likes to play football. <br>
        <input type="radio" name="question8" > He is friendly.<br>
        <input type="radio" name="question8" > He has a car.
    </div>
</div>
<br>

<br>


<button id="button1" class="button" onclick="viewScore()">Score Result</button>
<br>
<input type="text" id="grade1" value="" readonly>
<br>

<script src="testJs.js"></script>
```

and here is the testJs.js that i used:

```
     var score = 0;

    function viewScore() {
        var answer2 = document.getElementById("question2").value;
        var answer8 = document.getElementsByName("question8");
        var answer101 = document.getElementsByName("question101").value;


        if (answer2 == "Am") {
            document.getElementById("question2_answer").style.color = "green";
            document.getElementById("question2_answer").innerHTML = "&#10004";
            score += 1;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("question2_answer").style.color = "red";
            document.getElementById("question2_answer").innerHTML = "&#10006 Wrong!";
        }

        if (answer8[2].checked) {
            document.getElementById("question8_answer").style.color = "green";
            document.getElementById("question8_answer").innerHTML = "&#10004";
            score += 1;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("question8_answer").style.color = "red";
            document.getElementById("question8_answer").innerHTML = "&#10006 Wrong!";
        }
        if (answer101[0].checked) {
            document.

getElementsById("question101_answer").style.color = "green";
        document.getElementsById("question101_answer").innerHTML = "&#10004";
        score += 1;
    } else {
        document.getElementsByID("question101_answer").style.color = "red";
        document.getElementsByID("question101_answer").innerHTML = "&#10006 Wrong!";
    }


    if (score<=5) {
        document.getElementById("grade1").value = " Your total score is: "+ score+"    Your level is: "+"Elementary.";

    } else if(score<=8){
        document.getElementById("grade1").value = " Your total score is: "+ score+"    Your level is: "+"Pre Intermediate.";

    }else if(score<=15){
        document.getElementById("grade1").value = " Your total score is: "+ score+"    Your level is: "+"Intermediate.";

    }else{
        document.getElementById("grade1").value = " Your total score is: "+ score+"    Your level is: "+"Upper Intermediate.";

    }
    console.log(score);
    score = 0;
}
```

However, I'm getting following error on question 101. I check it several times and I have no idea where does this error coming from !  It refers to question 101 and mentions cannot read property '0' of undefined.
Thanks for any help in advance.

> testJs.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>       at viewScore (testJs.js:26)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (testHTML.html:57)

Comment: **All:** It's just a typo. @ Majid: `getElementsById` should be `getElementById` (singular).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My mistake. noted, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because in this line:

`var answer101 = document.getElementsByName("question101").value;`

you are putting the **value** of the input (which is NULL or UNDEFINED because the `HTMLCollection` returned by `getElementsByName` (note the plural) doesn't have a value property) into the `var answer101` and NOT the input itself.

To fix this, change the above line to:

`var answer101 = document.getElementsByName("question101");`

Comment: *"you are putting the value of the input (which is NULL or UNDEFINED when the page loads as it is not yet selected by the user)"* No, it's `undefined` because the HTMLCollection returned by `getElementsByName` (note the plural) doesn't have a `value` property. [More here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, I completely agree with you. Thanks for pointing this out. I have corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to select array (not value) for var answer101

```
var answer101 = document.getElementsByName("question101");
```

And correct if content for answer101

```
if (answer101[0].checked) {
            document.getElementById("question101_answer").style.color = "green";
            document.getElementById("question101_answer").innerHTML = "&#10004";
            score += 1;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("question101_answer").style.color = "red";
            document.getElementById("question101_answer").innerHTML = "&#10006 Wrong!";
        }
```